# TextHighlighter RichTextBlock UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, highlight

I would like to highlight some text of a richtextblock with `TextHighlighter` object.
I created a `TextRange`, I added this to a list, then I created a new instance of `TextHighlighter` and set the background color. But now I can not use the `TextHighlighter` to highlight the text. How should I proceed?

xaml:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
        <RichTextBlock x:Name="RichFullText" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Paragraph x:Name="Testo">
                <Run Foreground="Blue" FontSize="24" FontStyle="Italic">
                    This is a
                </Run>
                <Run Foreground="Teal" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="18" >
                    example text
                </Run>
                <Run Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
                    format
                </Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBox x:Name="txbToFind" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnToFind" Content="Find" Click="btnToFind_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnToFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange() { StartIndex = 3, Length = 5 };
        List<TextRange> rangelist = new List<TextRange>();
        rangelist.Add(textRange);
        TextHighlighter evidenziatore = new TextHighlighter() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) };
        //RichFullText... There I would apply highlight to RichTextBlock
    }
}
```

How can I highlight using `TextHighlighter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `TextHighlighter` to the `RichTextBlock`'s `TextHighlighters` collection:

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange() { StartIndex = 3, Length = 10 };            
TextHighlighter highlighter = new TextHighlighter()
{
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow),
    Ranges = { textRange }
};
//add the highlighter
RichBlock.TextHighlighters.Add(highlighter);
```

Also note that I have added the `textRange` to the `Ranges` collection in your `TextHighlighter` instance.

Comment: If that solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer so that the question is resolved :-)  . You can do so by clicking the grey tick mark.